# Yichud in a dorm like situation

Tags: halacha, yichud-seclusion

I was wondering if yichud is an issue in a situation like one that might arise on a college campus in an all girls dorm (apartment style- the building is mixed but each apartment is separate) if one night a guy sleeps over.

Dorm apartments are public enough that if the front door isnt locked chances are people will walk in freely during the day but in the end of the day they are real apartments not dorm rooms off a hallway.

My question is if in this situation there is a yichud issue? And if there is one if the fact that the girls out number the guy (6-1) helps and if not locking the front door would be enough to avoid a yichud issue or alternatively if locking yourself in your own rooms helps?

I'm looking for a general answer on the matter - the basic rules for yichud and ways of dealing with it and I'm sure many of you have thought about it in the context of a dorm situation at some point. Thankfully this is not an actual issue for me right now but its good information to have.

Comment: MEG welcome to the site. I'd like to remind you that we do not provide a substitute for qualified rabbinic advice. All discussions here are purely theoretical and anything you learn should be treated as something you heard from some friends. Looking forward to seeing you around!

Comment: I don't know enough to answer the rest of your question, but the Gemora says that yichud still applies even if there are 10 women in the room.

Comment: @avi - Where does the Gemara say this?

Comment: @AdamMosheh if my highschool memory is correct, somewhere in kedushin or ketubot.

Comment: It's likely to be towards the end of kiddushin, as that is where yichud is discussed.

Answer (score 4):

I can say that I did. I will provide you with a good website that sets out reasonable guidelines for the halakha, but rules of thumb are usually helpful so I will provide quick ones:
In Tur Shulhan Arukh, the precursor to the Shulkhan Arukh, in Even Ha-Ezer 22 it states that no matter how many women it is considered yihud still. The rational is interesting, but not something proper to mention in a public forum like this. This is codified by the Shulkhan Arukh (ibid) later on.
Now as for locking, yes not locking is the best solution. This is codified in the same place as mention

here is the website I mentioned earlier: http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/the-laws-of-yichud/index.html
also I have a transcript of a shiur on this issue which will be of great help, i think: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1YThu7QxoJpqt-2BvNzy8jK8cpcYsoardE21pwEGTJKQ/edit

Comment: Dead link......

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16023/in-a-non-jewish-youth-hostel-is-it-problematic-to-stay-in-a-mixed-gender-dorm-i