# Mixed apartments

Tags: halacha, home-house

The standard practice in my community is that unmarried men and women form single-sex apartments. Is this halachically required, preferable, or completely immaterial?

Comment: So much depends on the set up of the apartment.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I was wondering about that too. I haven't been in all that many of the Cambridge apts, but those I have been in are usually arrayed so as to have privacy for each person's bedroom. I don't know how universal this is though, so I'm not putting anything sufficiently general into the question.

Comment: How would yichud never be an issue?

Comment: @Loewian, good question

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16129/imagine-a-non-jewish-hostel-has-a-male-and-a-female-dorm-does-yichud-allow-me-t

Comment: @sabbahillel How do you know that? What issur is it? You don't even know what the place looks like.

Comment: I gather that these days, many religious communities would question immediately the possibilities of what COULD happen with girls and boys sharing the same apt. (They worry about them walking down the street together going to shul, sometimes not knowing they're siblings!) SO, while there may not be a problem of yichud if they have separate rooms in the apt. and no girl goes into a boy's bedroom or vice versa, there could be a *mar'it ayin* problem.